# Pulumi: empty stack

Tags: pulumi

I'm getting this output when I want to list my current stack:

[image]

I don't quite figure out why it's getting me this message.

This is my project:

[image]

Here you have code:

```
import * as k8s from "@pulumi/kubernetes";

const appLabels = { app: "nginx" };
const deployment = new k8s.apps.v1.Deployment("nginx", {
    spec: {
        selector: { matchLabels: appLabels },
        replicas: 1,
        template: {
            metadata: { labels: appLabels },
            spec: { containers: [{ name: "nginx", image: "nginx" }] }
        }
    }
});
export const name = deployment.metadata.apply(m => m.name);
```

I've tried to `up` current resources:

[image]

Comment: do you have kubeconfig with working kubernetes connection where pulumi expects it?

Comment: so basically, you need to have kubeconfig on this path: `~/.kube/config`

Comment: likely not. I've installed k3s. Where pulumi is expecting this kubeconfig be?

Comment: I'm quite sure it looks at all the default kubectl paths. for example the path I've specified

Comment: I've just figured out k3s generates a `kubeconfig` at `# Kubeconfig is written to /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because you didnt create any resources with `pulumi up` yet. `pulumi stack` only displays information about current stack state. after you run `pulumi up` and accept to create resources `pulumi stack` will show you that the resource is created.